# memcopy and 2d arrays

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, memcpy

```
struct item_CHECK_LIST_data
{

    char    list[MAX_CHECK_LIST_OPTIONS + 1][MAX_ITEM_TEXT_LEN];
    char    checkeditems[MAX_CHECK_LIST_OPTIONS + 1];//which are checked

    char    number_of_options;
};
```

can i copy this with memcopy?

I have a weird bug that would be explained by memcopy not being able to...

Comment: your "weird bug" is more likely to be your own rather than memcpy....please post you code.

Comment: You could post up the code that is giving you the problem.

Comment: What is "memcopy"? You will get more helpful answers by being accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can `memcpy` two-dimensional arrays in C, provided that they're actually 2D arrays and not a 1D array of pointers.  Two-dimensional arrays are laid out contiguously in memory, so `memcpy` will correctly read all the blocks.  However, if your array is a 1D-array of pointers to more 1D arrays, then the `memcpy` will only copy the pointers and you'll end up with a shallow copy rather than a deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use sizeof() to find how much to copy? The elements of the struct may be padded so the size is bigger than the sum of the parts

Comment: `char` should have no padding. OP is copying the array contained in the struct, not the struct itself.

Comment: @Jim - Sorry. I can only use SO from my iPhone for odd reasons and it's time consuming to type. The OP's question, as I read it, is about copying a 2D `char` array (that happens to be a member of a `struct`), not a 2D `struct` array as this answer seems to assume. There should be no difference between `N` and `sizeof(char[N])` so @Martin's answer is not really useful here (though it is in the more general case).

Comment: @Chris You posted an unsubstantiated claim and now back it up with a mere "as I read it". Well, Martin obviously read it differently; you aren't the one who is right just because you're you. To me, and to Martin, the OP's question appears to be about a struct that contains a 2D array -- why else would the whole struct be given? Martin's answer is really useful here if that's the case and, as I said, it certainly isn't clear that it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the struct as a whole that you want to copy, don't use `memcpy`. Just do an assignment, the `=` token is made for this.